# Could not Load Type from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net-core, reference, nuget

I have a solution that works on some computers and not others. The exception is this:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.Internal.NullScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Added information from Diagnostic set Output Build says:

> Exception Thrown: 'System.Exception' in Services.dll. Exception Thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.Corelib.dll

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the two computers and coming up short.

- Both computer that works/doesn't work are running VS2017 v15.9.17.
- Both computers have .NET Framework 4.0 installed
- Startup project uses C# 7.1
- Startup project is .NET Core 2.0
- Project that output says is throwing the error is .NET Standard 2.0
- The startup project is using dependency injection to create services that access a DB via DBContexts
- The call that is failing is:

```
CustomUnit unit = await _dbContext.CustomUnit
                    .Include(x => x.Type)
                    .Include(x => x.UnitBuckets)
                    .Include(x => x.InventoryBuckets)
                    .Include(x => x.WIPBuckets)
                        .ThenInclude(y => y.Unit)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UnitId == unitId);
```

The machines that work always work and the machines that don't never work. I've tried clearing the nuget cache, deleting and re-adding references, deleting and re-cloning project to new location all to no result. Since all machines have freshly pulled the code from the same branch with no modifcation, the code base is identical. I've been unable to find any differences between the two machines that would explain why it works on one and not the other. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Given this is running on .NET Core, run `dotnet --info` from the command line and make sure the same version of the runtime is installed on both machines. Also try running `dotnet publish` on both machines, copy the binaries to the other machine then run the binary on the other machine to see if it's an issue with the runtime, or build assets.

Comment: dotnet --info shows that they are running the same version. Interestingly, running dotnet publish on the machine that works resulted in an executable that did not work on the same machine. Does that mean VS is somehow accessing v2.2.0.0 internally so can see the NullScope object? It's worth noting that after speaking with Microsoft I have learned that NullScope only exists in 2.2.0.0 but isn't even an object in 3.0.0.0

Answer (score 23):

I solved it installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging' from Nuget

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix our issue

Comment: for me it also resolved the issue probably because  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution is now resolving the package to the version I explicitly specified. thx

Answer (score 6):

Issue resolved. I updated every Microsoft.Extensions nuget package in the project to 3.0.0.0 even if they seems unrelated to Logging.Abstractions and that resolved the issue.

Updated: 
1. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
4. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
5. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
6. Microsoft.Extensions.Options

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. I removed every 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' from my solution and that resolved the issue. No Need to thank me))

Comment: You're right, no need to thank you, because Microsoft.Extensions.Logging depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, thus your answer would result in code that cannot compile.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by manually loading in the project of the package into the solution, connecting it up as a package reference, then compiling, then restarting visual studio, then removing the project from solution so its back to how it was, then compiling again.

No idea why this fixed it for me, I assume this is a bug with visual studio...

Comment: This sounds oh so familiar...

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem again, and this time the issue was to do with my project having references to different versions of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.

For the most part, loaded packages for my solution where using 3.x (Serilog.AspNetCore 3.x) but for one package (in my case Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.x), version 2.x was loaded. For me, I couldn't upgrade this one, so I had to downgrade everything else so that the only version any package needed was 2.x.

Does anyone know if/why C# can't deal with multiple versions of the same package?